# My form is not working, please do tell me where it went wrong(PHP validation)

Tags: php, html, forms

I would like to know where in my code the form went wrong.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $arrayName = array("TeacherA", "TeacherB", "TeacherC" , "TeacherD", "TeacherE");

  $minimum = 5;
  $maximum = 10;

  $name = $_POST['yourName'];
  $email = $_POST['yourEmail'];

  if(strlen($name) < $minimum) {
    echo "Your name should be longer than 5 characters";
  } 
  
  if(strlen($name) > $maximum) {
    echo "Your name should not be longer than 10 characters";
  } 
  
  if(!in_array($name,$arrayName)){
    echo "Please do register with us before you can login";
  } else {
    echo "Welcome!";
  }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Blank</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="form.php" method="post">
    <label>Your Name:    </label>
    <input type="text" name="yourName"> <br>

    <label for="">Your E mail:</label>
    <input type="email" name="yourEmail" id=""><br>
    
    <!-- <textarea name="yourMessage" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea><br> -->
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I run through the localhost, however, I could not get result that I wanted.

The result that I wanted is if I didn't enter the names in the "Your Name" field, then it should show the result:

**Please do register with us before you can login**

Comment: What result did you get instead?

Comment: What happens instead? Blank page? Is that `form.php` you posted? Do you get any of the other messages (f.e. if the entered name is too short)?

Answer (score 1):

if the the "Your Name" field is empty, then its `strlen($name)` should be `0` and the first if statement is true  and it will show `Your name should be longer than 5 characters`
you can try this :

```
<?php   
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $arrayName = array("TeacherA", "TeacherB", "TeacherC", "TeacherD", "TeacherE");
    $minimum = 5;
    $maximum = 10;
    $name = $_POST['yourName'];
    $email = $_POST['yourEmail'];
    if (empty($name)) {
        echo "Please do register with us before you can login";
    } else {
        if (strlen($name) < $minimum) {
            echo "Your name should be longer than 5 characters";
        } else {
            if (strlen($name) > $maximum) {
                echo "Your name should be less than 10 characters";
            } else {
                if (in_array($name, $arrayName)) {
                    echo "Welcome!";
                } else {
                    echo "Your login is not correct";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

i used `empty()` to test if the field empty
and i used if-else statements because i want the script to stop if it founds a 'true' condition
in your script you can use `return;` but that will exit the rest of your script

have a nice code :)

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
if(!isset($name)){
  echo "Please do register with us before you can login";
}
else{
  echo "Welcome";
}
```

And also:

```
<input type="text" name="yourName" required>
```

Comment: Why should OP "try this"? What does it change? Where did OP go wrong in his code? Please add some explanation to answers